# Any non-negative integer can be written as the sum of distinct and non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci numbers  Fn are defined by the recurrence  Fn=Fn−1+Fn−2, with base cases  F0=0 and  F1=1.

Prove that any non-negative integer can be written as the sum of distinct and non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers. That is, if  FiFi  appears in the sum, then  Fi−1 and Fi+1  do not appear in the sum. For example:

17=F7+F4+F2

42=F9+F6

54=F9+F7+F5+F3+F1

How can i prove this?

Comment: Another one here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701888/proof-by-induction-that-if-n-in-mathbb-n-then-it-can-be-written-as-sum-of-di.

Comment: Note that the question in the first duplicate suggested bu Martin R is not quite the same, but the accepted answer does also answer this question.