# The Cartesian product of a finite number of countable sets is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> The **Cartesian product** of a family $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ is defined as $$\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i=\{f:I\to\bigcup A_i\mid f(i)\in A_i\}$$
>
> Let $I_n=\{i \in \mathbb N \mid i \le n\}$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ and $A_i$ be countable for all $i\in I_n$. Then $\prod\limits_{i\in I_n}A_i$ is countable.

---

**My attempt:**

**Lemma 1:** $(\prod\limits_{i\in I_n}A_i) \times A_{n+1}$ and $\prod\limits_{i\in I_{n+1}}A_i$ are equinumerous for all $n \in \mathbb N$. (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880477/how-can-i-prove-that-fa-n1-times-prod-i-in-i-na-i-to-prod-i-in-i-n1))

**Lemma 2:** If $A$ and $B$ are countable, then $A \times B$ is countable. (I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914598/if-a-and-b-are-countable-then-a-times-b-is-countable))

I will prove the theorem by induction on $n$. The theorem is trivially true for $n=0$. Assume that the theorem is true for $n=k$, then $\prod\limits_{i\in I_k}A_i$ is countable. Since $\prod\limits_{i\in I_k}A_i$ is countable (by inductive hypothesis) and $A_{k+1}$ is countable, then by **Lemma 2** $(\prod\limits_{i\in I_n}A_i) \times A_{n+1}$ is countable. Furthermore, by **Lemma 1** $(\prod\limits_{i\in I_k}A_i) \times A_{k+1}$ and $\prod\limits_{i\in I_{k+1}}A_i$ are equinumerous, then $\prod\limits_{i\in I_{k+1}}A_i$ is countable too. Thus the theorem is true for $n=k+1$. This completes the proof.

---

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

Comment: I don't understand why you need Lemma 1 at all. You could finish with "then by Lemma 2 (...) is countable." I think you need to prove lemma 2 (this is basically the heart of the original question)

Comment: @Yanko While it's very intuitive, I found quite embarrassed If I can not give a proof for it ^^

Comment: This is correct assuming you when you say $I_n=\{i \in \mathbb N \mid i \le n\}$ you mean $n\color{red}{\in\Bbb N}\mbox{ s.t. }I_n=\{i \in \mathbb N \mid  i \le n\}$

Comment: @LeAnhDung This is not so easy at all. Look here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable

Comment: @Yanko how from $(\prod\limits_{i\in I_n}A_i) \times A_{n+1}$ is countable you get $\prod\limits_{i\in I_{n+1}}A_i$ is countable without Lemma 1?

Comment: @Holo: that's not right! By your definition, every $I_n$ is equal to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, thanks for notifying me, I should have write this before the definition of the set(I edit it)

Comment: @Yanko Did you mean my proof is not correct? :)

Comment: Could some of you please have a check on my attempt?

Comment: @LeAnhDung Like I said, it is correct assuming the $n$ you are talking about are natural

Comment: @Holo, of course $n \in \Bbb N$ :)

Comment: @Holo I have edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: @LeAnhDung you would be surprised, "of course" is a dangerous statement :), but with the edit it is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be countable, i.e. we have the enumerations

$$a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$$ and $$b_1,b_2,b_3,\cdots$$

Then we can enumerate $A\times B$ as

$$(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_1),(a_1,b_2),(a_3,b_1),(a_2,b_2),(a_1,b_3),\cdots$$

(notice the sums of the indexes, $2,3,3,4,4,4,\cdots$). You can easily check that all pairs $(a_n,b_m)$ are cited.

Then by induction,

$$\prod_{i=1}^n A_i=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i\right)\times A_n.$$ is countable.

Comment: Hi @Yves, I have been thinking about your approach. Recently I have formalize it into a proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2918643/bbb-n-times-bbb-n-is-countably-infinite. Could you please have a look at it? Thank you so much :)

Comment: @LeAnhDung: sorry, I haven't had the courage to scrutinize it. The first part of my answer shows an easy bijection. Is there a need for more sophistication ?

Comment: It's ok :)  In my proof, I use a mapping $f$ such that $f(i,j)=i+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i+j}k$. I'm curious about your mapping. Please show it!

Comment: @LeAnhDung: on the sixth line.

Comment: It seems that your mapping is $f(i,j)=i+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i+j}k$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung: possibly, but I don't see a need for a formula. It is obvious that all sums of indexes are enumerated, and for a given sum, all possible pairs of indexes.

Comment: Did you mean: All sums of indexes are countable. And all pairs of indexes for a given sum are also countable.

Comment: @LeAnhDung: no, I said enumerated. This is a constructive answer.

Comment: Honestly, I think that if I wrote *Then we can enumerate $A\times B$ as $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_1),(a_1,b_2),(a_3,b_1),(a_2,b_2),(a_1,b_3),\cdots$*. I may receive such criticism from other users as *You are sloppy at that point* or *The general idea is good. You may want to give further justification for some statements. How do you know that there exists such a bijection* :)

Comment: @LeAnhDung: a matter of point of view. The case is simple enough that any reader can generalize and extend the sequence at will (in fact the notation defines an algorithm). You might consider that a plain summation is better, but it's just the same rigorous information presented differently.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LeAnhDung: but you are right, some people won't be open to this point of view.

Comment: I did meet some people of that kind in MSE :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier using prime factorization.

Map the j-th element of $A_i$
to $p_i^j$, where $p_i$ is the i-th prime
And multiply these representations to get the unique integer corresponding to any particular subset.

Comment: I got your solution @Marty. My main concern is the correctness of the above proof. Could you please verify it?

Answer (score 0):

With this inductive method, the heart of the matter boils down to proving $A\times B$ is countable -- your **Lemma 2**. While **Lemma 1** and the actual induction are necessary (and it was smart to notice that **Lemma 1** needs proving), a proof of **Lemma 2** is still essential.

Standard arguments for **Lemma 2** include primes like @Marty used or enumerating from a corner when considering the cartesian product as a table of pairs.

Comment: I have edited my post to indicate that $n \in \Bbb N$ and thus $I_n$ is finite.

Comment: Yep. The issue I'm seeing is with claiming $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ is countable. Even if $I_n$ is finite, absent a definition for $I$ we can't guarantee that $I$ is finite and that the product is countable.

Comment: Actually, $I_n$ is an initial segment of $\Bbb N$ :)

Comment: Yep, but what is $I$?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's a typo. It should be $$\prod\limits_{i\in I_n}A_i$$ rather than $$\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$$

Comment: That'll work much better :)

Comment: I have just presented a proof for **Lemma 2** at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914598/if-a-and-b-are-countable-then-a-times-b-is-countable. Please have a look if you don't mind!