# Two countable sets proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

If we know that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{N}$ (same cardinal), can we conclude that the cartesian product $A \times B$ of two countable sets $A$ and $B$ is countable? In particular I already proved that a bijection $\phi: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ exists such that $\phi(x, y) = x +\frac{(x + y -1)(x + y - 2)}{2}$. So, presuming that I am writing a formal proof, how would I show that $A \times B$ is countable? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: You’d need a lemma that if $X$ is the same cardinality of $A$ and $Y$ the same as $B$ then $X\times Y$ is the same cardinality as $A\times B.$ Then $A,B$ countable means $A\times B$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb N\times N$ which you have shown is the same cardinality as $\mathbb N.$ This lemma is not hard to prove.

Comment: @amwhy I disagree that the marked duplicate is a duplicate. Kraftsman specifically has trouble getting from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$, not showing that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Comment: I think in my search so far https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2914553/259262 has come closest to answering the question.

Comment: Bafflingly enough, I *still* haven't found a suitable answer other than mine, i.e. one that notes the reason it suffices to consider $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is because we can biject $A \times B$ with it.

Comment: I was just  going to check in, but your answer does not verify that A bijects with N, it merely claims it does, so I cannot yet find your answer suitable.  It's a one word sentence, followed by a question.  Hardly an answer.  If you want to sincerely answer, I'll reopen and upvote your answer. But as of know, your answer adds nothing.

Comment: @amwhy I answered as I did because I believe the question is one which requires a hint, not a solution. I have provided the domain and codomain of two bijections, thereby rephrasing the question to highlight precisely the important parts of it. I justify this based on https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28969/is-it-acceptable-to-leave-hints-as-answers, and in particular on my belief that a solution will be less helpful to the asker than a hint.

Comment: It's not helpful. You are selective in your links; only *good hints* can help a user move along.  Yours is not a good hint.. But I've seen you have a pattern, at least today, of answering questions that need to be closed.  I don't know anything to say anything more, but it does raise my concerns.

Comment: Please post comments about your answer below your answer.  If you address me again, below the question, I will repeat your address, and respond, below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. A[n infinite] countable set is one which bijects with $\mathbb{N}$, so can you build a bijection $A \times B \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and then to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You should have or should be developing a sense of when a question has already been answered on this site, this one many many times, searching for them, instead of providing one of dozens of answers.

Comment: Fair enough. This was faster and easier and I was lazy.

Comment: @amwhy Let us let the OP decide! We disagree about simple facts to which we have no access.

Comment: They are free to do that.